# SignalR connect to multiple servers

Tags: javascript, asp.net, signalr, signalr.client, signalr-backplane

Is possible to connect using Javascript client to more than one `SignalR` servers?

For example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://server1.net/signalr';
    var server1Hub = $.connection.server1Hub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    });

    // i need to connect to server2
    $.connection.hub.url = 'http://server2.net/signalr';
    var server2Hub = $.connection.server2Hub;

    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {

    });
</script>
```

Trying to connect (again) the second time gives me an error:

```
'server1Hub' Hub could not be resolved.
```

Can i create two instances of `$.connection` ? Obviously i think modifying the same `connection` can create many issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using different $connection:

```
var connection1 = $.connection('/first');
connection1.start();

var connection2 = $.connection('/second');
connection2.start();
```

Subscribing on multiple hubs:

```
var connection1 = $.hubConnection("'http://server1.net/signalr");
var connection2 = $.hubConnection("http://server2.net/signalr");

var Hub1= connection1.createHubProxy('Hub1');
var Hub2= connection2.createHubProxy('Hub2');

connection1.start();
connection2.start();
```

Read more here: 
[here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client) at section **Define method on client (without the generated proxy, or when adding after calling the start method)**

Answer (score 0):

Thank you  SilentTremor. You saved me a lot of time.

If you are working with generated proxies then you can use something like:

```
var Hub1 = connection1.createHubProxies().<your hub class>
```

Replace  with your own class. Then just get access to all server functions from Hub1. Example:

```
var Hub1 = connection1.createHubProxies().Chat;
...
Hub1.addMessage(name, message);
```