# Server hub connection from asp.net core 2.2 signalr console app

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I have a server running .net 4.5.1 with SignalR (IIS)

I want to connect to the server using a console client app on .net core 2,2.  I have installed the below Nuget package on the client

Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;

and have followed

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/dotnet-client?view=aspnetcore-2.2

I keep getting the below error

"There was an error opening the connection:System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found)."

The name of my Hub on the server is correct so I'm not sure of the problem

I have also tried

```
.WithUrl("http://172.10.0.20:81/client/?hub=myHub")
```

please help

```
connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()

//.WithUrl("http://172.10.0.20:81/client/?hub=myHub")

.WithUrl("http://172.10.0.20:81/myHub")

.Build();

connection.StartAsync().ContinueWith(task => {

if (task.IsFaulted)

{Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection:{0}",

task.Exception.GetBaseException());}

else

{Console.WriteLine("Connected");}}).Wait();

connection.StartAsync();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't reproduce your problem . But since your server is hosted on .net 4.5.1 , please make sure that you are using same version of SignalR both on server side and client side .

That means that you you cannot use the ASP.NET CORE SignalR (Hub or Client) with the ASP.NET SignalR (Hub or Client). You can't mix them. You can click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54131233/5751404) for more info .

Comment: without mixing them is it possible use ASP.NET SignalR (Hub or Client) in Net 6?

Answer (score 1):

thanks that pushed me in the right direction.
I'm using signalR with webforms so the hub is located at

`http://172.10.0.20:82/signalr/myHub`

After changing path I got the below informative error

```
There was an error opening the connection:System.IO.InvalidDataException: Invalid negotiation response received. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Detected a connection attempt to an ASP.NET SignalR Server. This client only supports connecting to an ASP.NET Core SignalR Server.
```

Comment: That is what i mean , "ASP.NET Core SignalR isn't compatible with clients or servers for ASP.NET SignalR." , see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/version-differences?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for more details .